# (Java) discord ping pong bot keeps on "pong"

Tags: java, discord

I am trying to make a simple discord ping pong bot, that will respond "pong" when I "!ping" problem is that it never stops.

pingpong class

```
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.events.message.MessageReceivedEvent;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.ListenerAdapter;


public class PingPong extends ListenerAdapter{

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent e){
        if (e.getMessage().getContentRaw().equals("!ping"));{
            e.getChannel().sendMessage("pong").queue();


        }
    }
}
```

Bot class

```
import javax.security.auth.login.LoginException;


public class Bot {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    JDABuilder jdaBuilder = JDABuilder.createDefault("token");
    JDA jda = null;
    try {
        jda = jdaBuilder.build();
    } catch (LoginException e ){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    PingPong pingPong = new PingPong();
    jda.addEventListener(pingPong);

}
}
```

I have watched a few tutorials, but I am not sure where this went wrong.

Comment: Could you add screen captures, log entries or debug info?

Comment: You have a semi-colon after your if which means the {} code always runs.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thank you.